# How Can I access Mac OS X Base System on Boot Screen?

Tags: macos, mac, startup, screen, accessibility

Im going to try to wipe out my hard drive and reinstall Mavericks but whenever i reboot the iMac and hit the OPTION key it won't show Mac OS X Base System. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the Recovery HD, then it means that you don't have a Recovery HD that's able to be booted into.

Try booting with ⌘R. If that fails, use ⌘⌥R for Internet Recovery.

Comment: None of them work. I use a 2007 iMac.

Comment: @JackTheGamer Unfortunately that Mac is [not able to be updated to have Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4904) (your Mac model wasn't detailed in the original question).